# Only load a script if another has loaded

Tags: jquery

I have an script to catch images from facebook, and another script to add a slider.
I want the slider script only load if the facebook script has loaded.

How i do that?

Comment: why dont you put the other to `onLoad` and the other on `ready`.

Comment: I put an setTimeout() and does1nt work :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the structure of your code. You should have 2 functions, 1 for catching images from Facebook and another one is for initiating the slider. Then inside function 1 you need to fire an event to notify function 2 that the images are finished loading, and then function 2 can do its things

That way your structure will be clearer and easier to maintain. And you don't have to mess around with injecting script tags manually, everything will be put in one file and loaded once

Comment: My facebook script creates a img tags, and i want to catch the dimensions of the images generated, but always return the value 0.
I think the slider is loaded first, and the facebook after :(

Comment: That is exactly what I mean, using events to control the flow. Let's say, after your Facebook function creates image tags, it will fire an event, `imageReady` for example. Then in your slider function, you listen to `imageReady` event and react accordingly. It depends on the library that you are using, so I can't show the concrete example. But that is pretty much the basic idea

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the existence of the `<script>` tag in question by selecting all of the `<script>` elements and checking their `src` attributes.

```
var len = $('script').filter(function () {
   return ($(this).attr('src') == '<facebook JS>');
}).length;

//if there are no scripts that match, the load it
if (len != 0) {
   $.getScript('<slider JS>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getScript('<facebook JS>',function(){
   $.getScript('<slider JS>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) can probably do this for you, but I do not recommend it for small apps since it adds up another 15kb of traffic.